# How to get the description entered in describe block? (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ui-automation, cypress

I am using cypress with typescript for my current project, I am in a situation to get the name of a saved screenshot. the screenshot name is automatically saved by cypress which starts with the description given in the describe block.

**for example**

```
describe('Admin Portal', () => {
  it('Login Test', () => {

  });
});
```

the screenshot will be saved as '**Admin Portal login -- Login Test (failed).png**'

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
if (test.state === 'failed') {
    const screenshotFileName = `${test.title} (failed).png`
    addContext({ test }, `assets/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`)
}
```

the above line of code is actually retrieving the name defined in the **It** block, how to get the name defined in the **describe** block??

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
if (test.state === 'failed') {
    const screenshotFileName = `${Cypress.config('screenshotsFolder')}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed).png`
    addContext({ test }, screenshotFileName)
}
```

})

Answer (score -1):

I have tried `console.log("=======>>>", Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.title)` in the `beforeEach()` section and it is displaying me the suite title name in the console.log(). 
So can you add `Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.title` and try the below code and let me know if it is working:

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
if (test.state === 'failed') {
    const screenshotFileName = `Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.title (failed).png`
    addContext({ test }, `assets/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`)
}
})
```

[image]

Comment: nope it is not working - at least for me :)